# Push Notification Entitlement is missing the On/Off toggle on the Signings and Capabilities tab,

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

I added Push Notifications to my project but I can't turn it on since there is no On/Off toggle.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SynrZ.jpg)

Comment: There is no on/off toggle in Xcode 11. If the capability is shown there it is on. If you remove it, it is off

Comment: Thank you!  Seems like you are the only person outside of Apple who knows this ;) .

Comment: It is just a change with how the capabilities tab works visually in Xcode 11